# Is there a name for this subset of bifunctors?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, functor, bifunctor

Bifunctors have a map function with this signature:

```hs
bimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
```

You could also have a map like this:

```hs
othermap :: ((a, c) -> (b, d)) -> p a c -> p b d
```

Types with this function are a strict subset of bifunctors (you can always define `bimap` using `othermap` but not vice versa). Is there a name for the second signature?

Follow-up: what about this intermediate function?

```hs
halfothermap :: ((a, c) -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
```

Comment: How would you implement this for `Either a c` for example, where you have either an `a` or a `c`, but not both at the same time?

Comment: I don't think this class would be much use. It is too strong – any bifunctor type implementing that signature has to be isomorphic to an ordinary functor wrapped around a tuple.

Comment: I'm only seeing Haskell code provided, and nothing specific to OCaml. Is the ocaml tag really relevant? (Perhaps the functional-programming tag is more relevant if this is a general FOP question with a Haskell example.

Comment: @Chris Good point, it is actually an OCaml question but I wrote it in Haskell to improve the pool of answerers.

Comment: You may wish to edit the question to clarify in that case.

Answer (score 7):

A type which is a Bifunctor need not have the same number of `a` values as `b` values. Consider, for example,

```
data TwoLists a b = TwoLists [a] [b]
```

It is easy to implement `bimap`, but `othermap` is a real problem, especially if one of the lists is empty.

```
othermap f (TwoLists [] (b:bs)) = TwoLists [] _
```

What can you do here? You need to call `f` to convert all the `bs` to a list of type `[d]`, but you can only call that function if you have an `a` in hand.

Perhaps even worse is a type which doesn't really ever have `b` values at all:

```
data TaggedFunction k a b = TaggedFunction a (k -> b)
instance Bifunctor (TaggedFunction k) where
  bimap f g (TaggedFunction a b) = TaggedFunction (f a) (g . b)
```

How can you implement `othermap` for this type? You could update the function, because you have an `a` in hand and will have a `b` by the time you need a `d`. But there's no way for you to replace the `a` with a `c`, because you can't get hold of a `b` to call `othermap`'s function with.

So you can't put this function in Bifunctor. Perhaps you're asking, why not put this in a new class? I think leftroundabout is right that the class is too constraining to be useful. `othermap` can be defined only when you have the same number of `a`s and `b`s in your structure, i.e. when your structure is some functor `f` wrapped around a tuple of type `(a, b)`. For example, instead of TwoLists we could have defined

```
newtype PairList a b = PairList [(a, b)]
```

and that can have an `othermap` definition. But it would just be

```
othermap f (PairList vs) = PairList (fmap f vs)
```

Likewise instead of TaggedFunction we could have defined

```
newtype MultiFunction k a b = MultiFunction (k -> (a, b))
```

but the `othermap` definition is again just a wrapped call to `fmap`:

```
othermap f (MultiFunction g) = MultiFunction (fmap f g)
```

So perhaps the best way to imagine defining this abstraction would be as, not a typeclass function, but an ordinary function that operates over a type that captures this composition:

```
newtype TupleFunctor f a b = TupleFunctor (f (a, b))

othermap :: Functor f => ((a, b) -> (c, d)) 
                      -> TupleFunctor f a b -> TupleFunctor f c d
othermap f (TupleFunctor x) = TupleFunctor (fmap f x)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did mean to ask about it as a subset of of bifunctors, have edited the question.

Comment: Is it definitely true/what is the reason that there have to be the same number of `a`s and `b`s, rather than at least one of each? I.e. why couldn't you define `othermap` for `(a, a, b)`? I think the answer might be "you would have to make an arbitrary choice and the result wouldn't satisfy the bifunctor laws" but not sure/can't think of an example.

Comment: I also edited the question with a follow-up about a function that seems intermediate between `bimap` and `othermap`.

Answer (score 3):

(Expanding on a comment by @glennsl...)

The *type* `p a c` "contains" both `a` and `c`.

But a function of type `(a, c) -> (b, d)` requires *values* of type `a` *and* `c` to be called, and a value of type `p a c` doesn't necessarily have both.

```
othermap @Either :: ((a, c) -> (b, d)) -> Either a c -> Either b d
othermap f (Left x) = ?
othermap f (Right y) = ?
```

There's no way for `othermap` to produce values of type `b` or `d`, because it can't call `f` in either case.

The type of the first argument implies a bifunctor that is isomorphic to `(,)`, which is not true of all possible bifuntors. `othermap` is, in fact, strictly *more* specific than `bimap`. (There seems to be a contravariant relationship here that I won't try to make precise.)